# How can I add arguments to run() method in java?

Tags: java

How can I add input arguments to run method in java threading?

```
@Override
public void run(int a, String b){
    // do something
}
// The method run(int) of type particle_explode must override or implement a supertype methodJava(67109498)
```

If I add argument, it said The method run(int) of type particle_explode must override or implement a supertype methodJava(67109498)

So how can I add argument to it?

Comment: Why do you need an argument? A `Thread` is single use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the values to the `Runnable` and have the `Thread` run that.

```
Runnable r = new MyRunnable(a, b);

new Thread(r).run();
```

If you need a convenient way to run a variety stuff in the background, `submit()` runnable things to an `Executor`.